# What is the reaction in a child's 'add water and watch the egg hatch' toy?

Tags: home-experiment

My son and daughter got given gifts where you place a plastic egg in water, and the (rubber?) toy inside expands (over three days) and breaks the shell of the egg so it 'hatches'.

[image][image]

I also observed that three weeks later the toys shrank again, but grew once placed in water.

I found the chemical reaction fascinating.

My question is: **What is the reaction in a child's 'add water and watch the egg hatch' toy?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The egg hatch toys are composed of a [superabsorbent polymer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabsorbent_polymer). These polymers are able to absorb up to 30 to 60 time their volume in water by forming hydrogen bonds with the water molecules.

Sodium polyacrylate ($\ce{[-CH2-CH(CO2Na){}-]}_n%edit$) is the most common superabsorbent polymer and according to its [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_polyacrylate), is the one used in the egg hatch toys.